# Serialize 'struct' with dynamically sized data to '&[u8]'

Tags: rust, serde

I am trying to create a generic serialization scheme for structs. Following an answer given on a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127165/how-to-convert-struct-to-u8), I have the following setup:

```
#[repr(packed)]
struct MyStruct {
    bytes: [u8; 4]
}

unsafe fn any_as_u8_slice<T: Sized>(p: &T) -> &[u8] {
    ::std::slice::from_raw_parts(
        (p as *const T) as *const u8,
        ::std::mem::size_of::<T>(),
    )
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct { bytes: [0u8, 1u8, 2u8, 3u8].to_owned() };
    
    let bytes: &[u8] = unsafe { any_as_u8_slice(&s) };
    
    println!("{:?}", bytes);
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c342efd822a9d896c60f9796f105cb4e))

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

This works great, however it does not take into account struct members that are dynamically sized like `Vec<u8>` and their size needs to determined at runtime. Ideally, I would like to encode each element in the `Vec<u8>` as bytes and add a prefix for indicating how many bytes to read.

At the moment I have this:

```
#[repr(packed)]
struct MyStruct {
    bytes: Vec<u8>
}

unsafe fn any_as_u8_slice<T: Sized>(p: &T) -> &[u8] {
    ::std::slice::from_raw_parts(
        (p as *const T) as *const u8,
        ::std::mem::size_of::<T>(),
    )
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct { bytes: [0u8, 1u8, 2u8, 3u8].to_vec() };
    
    let bytes: &[u8] = unsafe { any_as_u8_slice(&s) };
    
    println!("{:?}", bytes);
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d639de1940859574eb7133567ef08e00))

Output:

```
[208, 25, 156, 239, 136, 85, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I assume the output above is referencing a pointer of sorts, but I am not sure.

Currently, the `bincode` crate does this together with the `serde` crate, but it serializes the length of the vector as `usize`. I would rather want to specify this and encode the length as `u8`, as explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56219767/can-i-deserialize-vectors-with-variable-length-prefix-with-bincode). Unfortunately, the best solution here is to rewrite the `Bincode` library, which made me look for any alternative solution.

**EDIT**

Implementation using `serde` and `bincode`:

```
use serde::{Serialize};

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Serialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    bytes: Vec<u8>
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct { bytes: [0u8, 1u8, 2u8, 3u8].to_vec() };
    
    let bytes = bincode::serialize(&s).unwrap();
    
    println!("{:?}", bytes);
}
```

Output:

```
[4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Wanted output:

```
[4, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: @kmdreko That would be great, but I could not figure how to change the options. I edited the post, can you show where I can change the configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your only problem with `bincode` is the `usize` length prefix, you can [configure](https://docs.rs/bincode/1.3.3/bincode/config/index.html) it to use a variable-length prefix by using the [`with_varint_encoding`](https://docs.rs/bincode/1.3.3/bincode/config/trait.Options.html#method.with_varint_encoding) option.

```
use bincode::{DefaultOptions, Options};
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Serialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    bytes: Vec<u8>,
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct {
        bytes: [0u8, 1u8, 2u8, 3u8].to_vec(),
    };

    let bytes = DefaultOptions::new()
        .with_varint_encoding()
        .serialize(&s);

    println!("{:?}", bytes);
}
```

Output:

```
[4, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Would it be possible to set the ```with_varint_encoding``` option only for certain members in the struct? Changing this configuration seems to change all the serialization for all unsigned integers expect ```u8```.

Comment: @Kevin I do not know how that could be done, sorry.

Comment: @Kevin, did you figure out a way to change the int encoding for certain members?

Comment: @Keplerian No, I think I ended up creating two different structs with two different options for each case.

Answer (score 3):

The output you see for the `Vec` is exactly as expected. A `Vec` has three elements, a pointer, the length, and its capacity. This is [guaranteed by the standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#guarantees). In your case you have the pointer and both length and capacity are the number 4 in little endian.

It is impossible to turn a struct containing a `Vec` into `&[u8]` the way you want. A `&[u8]` slice is a contiguous piece of memory, however, a `Vec` is fundamentally an indirection, meaning its elements are not stored contiguous to the rest of the struct.
At least, you need to collect the bytes into a `Vec<u8>` or similar, since you need to copy data from multiple places.