# Deserialize Vec<u8> with nonstandard length encoding

Tags: rust, serde, bincode

I am trying to use serde together with bincode to de-serialize an arbitrary [bitcoin network message](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Message_structure). Given that the payload is handled ubiquitously as a byte array, how do I de-serialize it when the length is unknown at compile-time? `bincode` does by default handle `Vec<u8>` by assuming it's length is encoded as `u64` right before the elements of the vector. However, this assumption does not hold here because the **checksum** comes after the **length** of the payload.

I have the following working solution

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "serde-test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_bytes = "0.11"
bincode = "1.3.3"
```

**main.rs**

```
use bincode::Options;
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer, de::{SeqAccess, Visitor}};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Message {
    // https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Message_structure
    magic: u32,
    command: [u8; 12],
    length: u32,
    checksum: u32,
    payload: Vec<u8>,
}

struct MessageVisitor;
impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for MessageVisitor {
        type Value = Message;

    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        formatter.write_str("Message")
    }

    fn visit_seq<V>(self, mut seq: V) -> Result<Self::Value, V::Error> where V: SeqAccess<'de>,
    {
        let magic = seq.next_element()?.unwrap();
        let command = seq.next_element()?.unwrap();
        let length: u32 = seq.next_element()?.unwrap();
        let checksum = seq.next_element()?.unwrap();
        let payload = (0..length).map(|_| seq.next_element::<u8>().unwrap().unwrap()).collect();
        // verify payload checksum (omitted for brevity)

        Ok(Message {magic, command, length, checksum, payload})
    }
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Message {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Message, D::Error> where D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        deserializer.deserialize_tuple(5000, MessageVisitor) // <-- overallocation
    }
}

fn main() {
    let bytes = b"\xf9\xbe\xb4\xd9version\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00_\x1ai\xd2r\x11\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbc\x8f^T\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xc6\x1bd\t \x8d\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xcb\x00q\xc0 \x8d\x12\x805\xcb\xc9yS\xf8\x0f/Satoshi:0.9.3/\xcf\x05\x05\x00\x01";

    let msg: Message = bincode::DefaultOptions::new().with_fixint_encoding().deserialize(bytes).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", msg);
}
```

Output:

```
Message { magic: 3652501241, command: [118, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], length: 101, checksum: 3530103391, payload: [114, 17, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 188, 143, 94, 84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 198, 27, 100, 9, 32, 141, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 203, 0, 113, 192, 32, 141, 18, 128, 53, 203, 201, 121, 83, 248, 15, 47, 83, 97, 116, 111, 115, 104, 105, 58, 48, 46, 57, 46, 51, 47, 207, 5, 5, 0, 1] }
```

I dislike this solution because of how `payload` is handled. It requires me to allocate some "large enough" buffer to take into account the dynamic size of the `payload`, In the code snippet above 5000 is sufficient. I would much rather de-serialize `payload` as a single element and use `deserializer.deserialize_tuple(5, MessageVisitor)` instead.

---

Is there a way to handle this kind of deserialization in a succint manner?

Similar question I could find: [Can I deserialize vectors with variable length prefix with Bincode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56219767/can-i-deserialize-vectors-with-variable-length-prefix-with-bincode)

Comment: Maybe try using the `nom` crate? Or try parsing byte-by-byte and grouping into numbers with e.g. `let length = u32::from_le_bytes([...])`?

Comment: @Coder-256 I have not heard of the ```nom``` crate until now, is it a replacement for ```serde``` ? I am not sure what you mean by parsing byte-by-byte, the ```length``` encoding is not really the problem, but rather that it is not immediately followed the elements in ```payload```.

Comment: you can't use bincode and call it a day LUL bincode is for bincode encoding nothing more. Use nom

Comment: also https://lib.rs/crates/bitcoin

Comment: @Kevin nom is not a replacement for serde, it's just a different approach. Your problem is that your message is not encoded as bincode, so you are doing weird things to treat non-bincode data as if it was. Serde is for creating serializers and deserializers for general-purpose formats, but your message is in a very specific format that can only be interpreted one way. A library like nom is much more suitable. You could also just look at the bytes directly, since it is a simple format.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the source message is not encoded as bincode, so you are doing weird things to treat non-bincode data as if it was.

Serde is designed for creating serializers and deserializers for general-purpose formats, but your message is in a very specific format that can only be interpreted one way.

A library like nom is much more suitable for this kind of work, but it may be overkill considering how simple the format is and you can just parse it from the bytes directly:

```
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn main() {
    let bytes = b"\xf9\xbe\xb4\xd9version\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00_\x1ai\xd2r\x11\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbc\x8f^T\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xc6\x1bd\t \x8d\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xcb\x00q\xc0 \x8d\x12\x805\xcb\xc9yS\xf8\x0f/Satoshi:0.9.3/\xcf\x05\x05\x00\x01";

    let (magic_bytes, bytes) = bytes.split_at(4);
    let magic = u32::from_le_bytes(magic_bytes.try_into().unwrap());
    let (command_bytes, bytes) = bytes.split_at(12);
    let command = command_bytes.try_into().unwrap();
    let (length_bytes, bytes) = bytes.split_at(4);
    let length = u32::from_le_bytes(length_bytes.try_into().unwrap());
    let (checksum_bytes, bytes) = bytes.split_at(4);
    let checksum = u32::from_le_bytes(checksum_bytes.try_into().unwrap());
    let payload = bytes[..length as usize].to_vec();

    let msg = Message {
        magic,
        command,
        length,
        checksum,
        payload,
    };

    println!("{:?}", msg);
}
```

There are hundreds of cryptocurrency projects in Rust and there are many crates already written for handling cryptocurrency data structures. These crates are battle-tested and will have much better error-handling (my example above has none). As mentioned in the comments, you can perhaps look at the [bitcoin crate](https://lib.rs/crates/bitcoin).